# couldn't find file 'css/font-awesome' with type 'text/css'

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I have downloaded font-awesome to:
/app/assets/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0

When I open I page I receive:

```
couldn't find file 'css/font-awesome' with type 'text/css'
Checked in these paths: 
  /home/dercni/Documents/oink201705/app/assets/config
  /home/dercni/Documents/oink201705/app/assets/fonts
  /home/dercni/Documents/oink201705/app/assets/images
  /home/dercni/Documents/oink201705/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/dercni/Documents/oink201705/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/dercni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/cocoon-1.2.10/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/dercni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/dercni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/jquery-turbolinks-2.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/dercni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
  /home/dercni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actioncable-5.1.1/lib/assets/compiled
  /home/dercni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-5.1.1/lib/assets/compiled
  /home/dercni/Documents/oink201705/node_modules
  /home/dercni/Documents/oink201705/app/assets/fonts
  /home/dercni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets
  /home/dercni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/javascripts
  /home/dercni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/fonts
  /home/dercni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/images
```

And below that:

```
Extracted source (around line #15):
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require css/font-awesome
 *= require css/govicons
 */
#activity_outer.in,
```

When I move these individual font folders up one level they work, so they are located at:
/app/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0

I would be more structured to store all fonts in a fonts folder rather than straight under assets however I cannot see where to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, Rails is looking in 
`/home/dercni/Documents/oink201705/app/assets/fonts`

but it's not finding `css/font-awesome` in it.

If `css/font-awesome` is still in the enclosing `font-awesome-4.7.0` directory, try writing your require statement to include that directory name in the path:

`*= require font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome`

Comment: Thanks but this is not correct. Currently there is no css directory other than within the font-awesome-4.7.0 folder. Working path is /app/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0 When directly under assets it finds the css folder within the font-awesome-4.7.0 folder however under /assets/fonts it cannot find it.

Comment: it's been a long day... one moment